# My image is not displaying in my list

Tags: java, android, retrofit, picasso

I'm using retrofit to communicate with sever and get a list of news from it then I need to display news in my app ( every news is 2 textview and 1 imageview). TextViews are working great but I have problem with imageview. Here is the code for my adapter:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<News> news;
public NewsAdapter(ArrayList<News> news) {
    this.news=news;
}

public void clearData() {
    // clear the data
    news.clear();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return news.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return news.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=null;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.novosti_item,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{
        view = convertView;
        viewHolder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    News news = (News) getItem(position);

    if(news != null) {

        viewHolder.intro.setText(news.getIntro());
        viewHolder.naziv.setText(news.getSubject());
        Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(news.getImagePath()).fit().centerCrop().into(viewHolder.slika);
    }

    return view;


}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView naziv;
    TextView intro;
    ImageView slika;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {

        this.naziv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.novosti_title);
        this.intro=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.novosti_desc);
        this.slika=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.novosti_slika);


    }



}
}
```

I'm quite sure that problem is in this line :;

```
      Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(news.getImagePath()).fit().centerCrop().into(viewHolder.slika);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Adapter Constructor

```
   private Activity mActivity;
        public NewsAdapter(ArrayList < News > news, Activity mActivity) {
            this.news = news;
            this.mActivity = mActivity;
        }

        if (news.getImagePath() != null) {
            Picasso.with(mActivity).load(news.getImagePath()).centerCrop().into(viewHolder.slika);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(mActivity).load(news.getImagePath()).centerCrop().placeHolder("placeholder").into(viewHolder.slika);

        }
```

Comment: If i do that I have another problem:
http://pokit.org/get/?d6d8bcc9bc3a6a12ddfa7b019788dc3b.jpg

Comment: which problem ?? @Spirit

Comment: I sent you image above here it is : http://pokit.org/get/?d6d8bcc9bc3a6a12ddfa7b019788dc3b.jpg that's when I try to set that adapter.

Comment: just past the list and activitycontext

Answer (score 0):

Change your Adapter

```
private Context mContext;
public NewsAdapter(ArrayList<News> news, Context context) {
       this.news=news;
       this.mContext = context;
  }
```

and

`Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(news.getImagePath()==null ? yourPlaceHoder : news.getImagePath())
       .fit()
       .centerCrop()
       .into(viewHolder.slika);`